# How can I have BST datetime objects?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I am trying to comprare many aware datetime objects. I found `pytz` but haven't found the BST timezone or how to create custom timezones so I can have UTC+1 during british summer time. Anyways, I figured out a workaround that works but I am pretty sure there is another, better, way so I am sharing it below.

Based on [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2019) for London which is the area that interests me:

> Sunday, 31 March 2019, 01:00:00 clocks were turned forward 1 hour to
>   Sunday, 31 March 2019, 02:00:00 local daylight time instead.

So tz_1 and tz_2 should be UTC, whereas tz_3 should be BST.

```
import datetime
import pytz

tz_1 = pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 30, 9, 15)).tzinfo
tz_2 = pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 9, 15)).tzinfo
tz_3 = pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 9, 15)).tzinfo

date1 = datetime.datetime(2019 , 4, 25, tzinfo = tz_1)
date2 = datetime.datetime(2019 , 4, 25, tzinfo = tz_2)
date3 = datetime.datetime(2019 , 4, 25, tzinfo = tz_3)

utc_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 25, tzinfo = pytz.UTC)

print ("Date 1:   ", date1, date1.tzinfo) # Timezone returns Europe/London
print ("Date 2:   ", date1, date2.tzinfo) # Timezone returns Europe/London
print ("Date 3:   ", date1, date3.tzinfo) # Timezone returns Europe/London
print ("UTC date: ", utc_date, utc_date.tzinfo) # Timezone returns UTC

print (date1 > date2) # returns True
print (date2 > date3) # returns False
print (date3 > date1) # returns False
```

The comparisons are correct but the visualization is not that good since all of them return "Europe/London" as timezone. So it is hard for me to understand if a datetime object is during the BST time of London or the UTC time of London.

Also you are going to notice that I am forcing a timezone to the date 2019-04-25. The timezone should have been BST but I am also forcing it a UTC timezone. I am going to force timezones to objects during my script since I am reading them from .csvs and they are read as strings and not as datetime objects.

So my final question, how can I have datetime objects with BST?

Comment: `pytz` uses *zone* in a geographical sense (obvious exceptions being GMT and UTC): you can map them. In regions that have DST, there are 2 *offsets* from UTC, as in EST/EDT. The offsets are also called *timezones* but using that sense leads to confusions between time and space such as the Windows registry's entries for *GMT Standard Time* and *GMT Daylight Time*, neither of which exist outside of Redmond. Saying that Arizona is on Mountain Time in summer and Pacific Time in winter does not mean that Phoenix magically moves 1800 km westwards in March, only that its UTC offset remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

To check if a datetime is within BST (British Summer Time), check the `dst()` (daylight savings adjustment) function of your timezone object:

```
print('Is Summer time?')
print(date1, tz_1.dst(date1) != datetime.timedelta(0))
print(date2, tz_2.dst(date2) != datetime.timedelta(0))
print(date3, tz_3.dst(date3) != datetime.timedelta(0))
```